# Dummy Sound on Asus X550JK on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, asus, output

I've got a problem with the soundcard on my Asus. In sound settings I've got an dummy output against the built-in speakers. When I execute `aplay -l` in the terminal, I recieve `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`. I've tried to reinstall pulseaudio and the alsa drivers, but it's still not detecting my soundcard.

Comment: Does alsamixer shows a sound card?

Comment: I don't know yet. how to check it?

Comment: alsamixer don't show it

Comment: What does the command `cat /proc/asound/cards` say? And `lspci -v`?

Comment: `cat /proc/asound/cards` returns `cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory`
and `lspci -v` returns [this](http://pastebin.com/Qvu28u2a)

Comment: On line 45 it founds a soundcard. Can you give the outut of `lsmod`?

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/wquBHvuN

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the kernel module for sound isn't loaded.
Try enabling the following modules with `modprobe <module>`

- snd_hda_codec_realtek
- snd_hda_codec_generic
- snd_hda_intel
- snd_hda_controller
- snd_hda_codec
- snd_hwdep
- snd_pcm
- snd_timer
- snd
- soundcore